# Evaluation in arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint

I'm new to arrow functions and I'm trying to only add to the array when it's not undefined but I can't figure out the syntax. How should I write the if-statement below? Thanks!

```
let carList = cars.map(car => (
  if(car.owner !== "undefined"){ // this is the condition I want.
  do something
 }
));
```

Comment: I find that a good place to look for javascript is [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: `map` creates an item for every item in the source array, period. If you need to filter them, then use `filter` first. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 3):

Like any other function, the body must be in curly braces, not parentheses:

```
let carList = cars.map(car => {
   // code here
});
```

Remember that `map()` creates a new element for each element in the original array. If you want to only perform an operation over certain elements of the list, you should use `filter()` first:

```
let carList = cars.filter(car => {
   return car.owner !== undefined
}).map(car => {
   // Do something to each car
});
```

Note that `undefined` is a keyword and does not require quotes. Using the string value `"undefined"`, while legal, can be incredibly confusing, so I advise against it.

Comment: Thanks but I just wrote pseudo code. I am looping through it but my problem is that I don't know how to disregard the cars with undefined owners.

Comment: @J.Doe The second part of my answer addresses that. You may need to refresh the page to see my edits.

Comment: "Like any other function, the body must be in curly braces, not parentheses:" This isn't true. It is in this case, but it's not universal.

Comment: Thank you, I saw now and will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) rather than `map`:

```js
const cars = [
  { owner: '', age: 12 },
  { owner: 'bob', age: 1 },
  { owner: undefined, age: 2 },
  { owner: 'steve', age: 13 },
  { age: 1 }
];

let carList = cars.filter(car => car.owner);

console.log(carList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add typeof if you want to do the comparison via string.
Also, encase the function in curly braces.

```
let carList = cars.map(car => {
  if(typeof(car.owner) !== "undefined"){ // this is the condition I want.
  do something
 }
});
```

or ditch the string quotes

```
let carList = cars.map(car => {
  if(car.owner !== undefined){ // this is the condition I want.
  do something
 }
});
```

Or just use a boolean not.

```
let carList = cars.map(car => {
  if(!car.owner){ // this is the condition I want.
  do something
 }
});
```

```js
let cars = [{},{owner:'foo'},{owner:'bar'}, {fun:'none'}];
let carList = cars.map(car => {
  if(!car.owner){ // this is the condition I want.
    console.log(car,'has no owner');
 }}
);
```